# Separating socket.io logic from app.js in feathersjs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I currently have the following in configuration for socket.io in my app.js file:

```
app
.configure(feathers.socketio(function(io){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('connect',{test: 'wow'});
        socket.on('createRecord', function(socket){
            analytics.service('record').create({type: socket.name, user: socket.interest}, function(error, user){
            });
        })
    })

}))
```

The above works fine, but is there a way to separate the socket.io logic from the app.js, as it will get very large as I continue on adding more emit and on methods.  I am aware this can be done by passing the socket object into as an argument into a module in another file and using it from there.  However, I am not sure how to proceed with that in feathersjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly extracting

```
module.exports = feathers.socketio(function(io){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('connect',{test: 'wow'});
        socket.on('createRecord', function(socket){
            analytics.service('record').create({type: socket.name, user: socket.interest}, function(error, user){
            });
        })
    })

})
```

to `./socketsConfig` and

```
var socketsConfig = require('./socketsConfig')
app.configure(socketsConfig);
```

will do the job.